# Создание события C#

Tags: c#, события, winforms

В моем распоряжении есть:

- Главная форма, которая содержит DataGridView.
- Дополнительная форма, где я ввожу данные создаваемого объекта
- Библиотека классов.

На главной форме есть кнопка "AddObjectButton", кликая по которой открывается дополнительная форма. В дополнительной форме, после ввода данных об объекте, по нажатию на кнопку "Добавить объект" вызывается конструктор объекта, описанный в библиотеке классов. Этот объект добавляется в коллекцию (List<>), которая является статическим членом класса "Главная форма". После этого форма для ввода данных закрывается.

Задача: с появлением новых объектов в коллекции отобразить их наличие в DataGridView. Если я правильно понимаю, то можно создать событие, которое будет реагировать на создание объекта и вызывать метод отображения этого объекта в DataGridView.

Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам следует создать свой класс, унаследованный от List, затем добавить к нему эвент.

Делается примерно так:

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
public event EventHandler OnAdd;

public void Add(T item)
{
   if (null != OnAdd)
   {
       OnAdd(this, null);
   }
   base.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Затем вешаете обработчик в форме:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyList<int> l = new MyList<int>();
    l.OnAdd += new EventHandler(l_OnAdd);
    l.Add(1);
}
```

Создано по мотивам [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299920/how-to-handle-add-to-list-event).

Comment: Спасибо, понял)

Comment: А почему не ObservableCollection? Проблема с таким расширением List в том, что метод Add в базовом классе невиртуальный.